# Missing Items in Listview Component

Tags: android, react-native

Hi guys need help on this one. I've attached a screenshot with the UI, the array and the ListView code snippet. As you can see in the screenshot, there are items in the array that were not displayed in the ListView component. Appreciate all the help guys thanks!

[image]

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: the code is in the attached image

Comment: Code in image is hard to read and understand.

Comment: hmm really hard to explain this. can we have skype? ill show you my code and the scenario. really desperate here

Comment: why is it hard to post the code?